# Why is Direct2D not drawing to the screen

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, assembly, direct2d

I couldn't get it to work in pure assembly so i tried making C code to draw to the screen but the C code won't do it either and i don't know why and nothing is giving error codes. Im trying to draw directly onto the screen with Direct2D through a GDI DC.

My C code,  sorry if its a little messy it was supposed to be temporary for a quick fix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")

extern "C" ID2D1Bitmap* mybitmapcreate(ID2D1DCRenderTarget*);
float left = 5;
float top = 10;
float Bottom = 10;
float Right = 30;
ID2D1Bitmap* picbitmap;

D2D1_RECT_F myrect = D2D1::RectF(left, top, Bottom, Right);
ID2D1DCRenderTarget* pow;
ID2D1Bitmap* mybitmap;
ID2D1Factory *l;
REFIID x = __uuidof(ID2D1Factory);

struct D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
    D2D1::PixelFormat(
        DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
        D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
    0,
    0,
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE,
    D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT
);
struct D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES bitmapprops = D2D1::BitmapProperties(
    D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_UNKNOWN), 96.0, 96.0
);

int main()
{
    /*
    long bufferend;
    FILE* mybitmapfile;
    char* mybitmaparray;
    //size_t result;
    mybitmapfile = fopen("bitmap.bin", "rb");
    if (mybitmapfile == NULL) { fputs("File error", stderr); exit(1); }
    fseek(mybitmapfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    //bufferend = ftell(mybitmapfile);
    bufferend = 1204097;
    rewind(mybitmapfile);
    mybitmaparray = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*bufferend);
    if (mybitmaparray == NULL) { fputs("Memory error", stderr); exit(2); }
    fread(mybitmaparray, 1, bufferend, mybitmapfile);
    fclose(mybitmapfile);
    */
    HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &l);
    l->CreateDCRenderTarget(&props, &pow);
    picbitmap = mybitmapcreate(pow);
    pow->BeginDraw();
    while (true) {
        pow->DrawBitmap(picbitmap, myrect, 1.0F, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, myrect);
    };
    pow->EndDraw();
    return 0;
}
```

This is mybitmapcreate, its return value is the bitmap.

```
includelib user32.lib
includelib D2D1.lib
include externals.asm
include wincons.asm
include vtable.asm

.data
include variables.asm
include pic.asm
include riid.asm
include structures.asm
.code
public mybitmapcreate
bitmapcreate proc frame
mybitmapcreate::
    DB 48h
    push rbx
    .pushreg rbx
    push r13
    .pushreg r13
    push rbp
    .pushreg rbp
    sub rsp, 80
    .allocstack 80
    lea rbp, [rsp + 80]
    .setframe rbp, 80
    .endprolog
    mov ID2D1DCRenderTarget, rcx
    call __imp_GetDesktopWindow
    mov rcx, 0
    mov rbx, rax
getdcfail:
    call __imp_GetDC
    cmp rax, 0
    je getdcfail
    mov rcx, rbx
    lea rdx, ScreenSize
    mov screendc, rax
    call __imp_GetWindowRect
    mov rcx, ID2D1DCRenderTarget
    mov rbx, [rcx]
    mov rdx, ScreenDC
    lea r8, ScreenSize
    call ID2D1DCRenderTarget_BindDC
    mov rcx, ID2D1DCRenderTarget
    mov rbx, [rcx]
    mov rdx, 000000199000002E0h
    lea r8, pic1colorbytes
    mov r9, 2944
    lea rax, pic1properties
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], rax
    lea rax, ID2D1Bitmap1
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 28h], rax
    call ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateBitmap
    mov rax, ID2D1Bitmap1
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    pop r13
    pop rbx
    ret
bitmapcreate endp
end
```

This is my vtable

```
;ID2D1RenderTargetVtbl
    ID2D1RenderTarget_QueryInterface                  textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+0]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_AddRef                          textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+8]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_Release                         textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+16]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetFactory                      textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+24]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateBitmap                    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+32]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap       textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+40]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateSharedBitmap              textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+48]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateBitmapBrush               textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+56]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateSolidColorBrush           textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+64]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateGradientStopCollection    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+72]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateLinearGradientBrush       textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+80]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateRadialGradientBrush       textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+88]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateCompatibleRenderTarget    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+96]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateLayer                     textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+104]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_CreateMesh                      textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+112]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawLine                        textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+120]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawRectangle                   textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+128]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_FillRectangle                   textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+136]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawRoundedRectangle            textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+144]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_FillRoundedRectangle            textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+152]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawEllipse                     textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+160]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_FillEllipse                     textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+168]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawGeometry                    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+176]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_FillGeometry                    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+184]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_FillMesh                        textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+192]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_FillOpacityMask                 textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+200]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawBitmap                      textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+208]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawText                        textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+216]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawTextLayout                  textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+224]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_DrawGlyphRun                    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+232]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_SetTransform                    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+240]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetTransform                    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+248]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_SetAntialiasMode                textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+256]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetAntialiasMode                textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+264]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_SetTextAntialiasMode            textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+272]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetTextAntialiasMode            textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+280]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_SetTextRenderingParams          textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+288]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetTextRenderingParams          textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+296]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_SetTags                         textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+304]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetTags                         textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+312]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_PushLayer                       textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+320]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_PopLayer                        textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+328]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_Flush                           textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+336]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_SaveDrawingState                textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+344]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_RestoreDrawingState             textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+352]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_PushAxisAlignedClip             textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+360]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_PopAxisAlignedClip              textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+368]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_Clear                           textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+376]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_BeginDraw                       textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+384]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_EndDraw                         textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+392]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetPixelFormat                  textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+400]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_SetDpi                          textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+408]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetDpi                          textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+416]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetSize                         textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+424]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetPixelSize                    textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+432]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_GetMaximumBitmapSize            textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+440]>
    ID2D1RenderTarget_IsSupported                     textequ       <qword ptr [rbx+448]>
;ID2D1Factory
    ID2D1Factory_QueryInterface                     textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+0]>
    ID2D1Factory_AddRef                             textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+8]>
    ID2D1Factory_Release                            textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+16]>
    ID2D1Factory_ReloadSystemMetrics                textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+24]>
    ID2D1Factory_GetDesktopDpi                      textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+32]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateRectangleGeometry            textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+40]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateRoundedRectangleGeometry     textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+48]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateEllipseGeometry              textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+56]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateGeometryGroup                textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+64]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateTransformedGeometry          textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+72]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreatePathGeometry                 textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+80]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateStrokeStyle                  textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+88]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateDrawingStateBlock            textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+96]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget        textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+104]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateHwndRenderTarget             textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+112]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget      textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+120]>
    ID2D1Factory_CreateDCRenderTarget               textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+128]>
;dcrendertarget
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_QueryInterface                  textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+0]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_AddRef                          textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+8]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_Release                         textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+16]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetFactory                      textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+24]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateBitmap                    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+32]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap       textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+40]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateSharedBitmap              textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+48]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateBitmapBrush               textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+56]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateSolidColorBrush           textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+64]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateGradientStopCollection    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+72]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateLinearGradientBrush       textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+80]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateRadialGradientBrush       textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+88]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateCompatibleRenderTarget    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+96]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateLayer                     textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+104]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_CreateMesh                      textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+112]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawLine                        textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+120]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawRectangle                   textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+128]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_FillRectangle                   textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+136]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawRoundedRectangle            textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+144]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_FillRoundedRectangle            textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+152]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawEllipse                     textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+160]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_FillEllipse                     textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+168]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawGeometry                    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+176]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_FillGeometry                    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+184]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_FillMesh                        textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+192]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_FillOpacityMask                 textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+200]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawBitmap                      textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+208]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawText                        textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+216]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawTextLayout                  textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+224]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_DrawGlyphRun                    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+232]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_SetTransform                    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+240]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetTransform                    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+248]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_SetAntialiasMode                textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+256]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetAntialiasMode                textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+264]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_SetTextAntialiasMode            textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+272]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetTextAntialiasMode            textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+280]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_SetTextRenderingParams          textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+288]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetTextRenderingParams          textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+296]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_SetTags                         textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+304]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetTags                         textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+312]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_PushLayer                       textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+320]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_PopLayer                        textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+328]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_Flush                           textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+336]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_SaveDrawingState                textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+344]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_RestoreDrawingState             textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+352]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_PushAxisAlignedClip             textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+360]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_PopAxisAlignedClip              textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+368]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_Clear                           textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+376]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_BeginDraw                       textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+384]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_EndDraw                         textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+392]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetPixelFormat                  textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+400]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_SetDpi                          textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+408]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetDpi                          textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+416]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetSize                         textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+424]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetPixelSize                    textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+432]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_GetMaximumBitmapSize            textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+440]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_IsSupported                     textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+448]>
    ID2D1DCRenderTarget_BindDC                          textequ     <qword ptr [rbx+456]>
```

Comment: [Direct2D Debug Layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2ddebuglayer-portal).

Comment: the only errors i got were memory leaks, caused by not releasing,  it wouldn't make direct2D not draw.

Comment: i released everything at the end of the program now there are no errors and it is still not drawing to the screen.

Comment: the operator: `::` is a C++ operator, so why why the `c` tag rather than a `c++` tag?

Comment: Check the return value of EndDraw(). Doing all that in asm is totally futile.

Comment: EndDraw(); returns 0.

Comment: If you can't make it work with a high level language, why are you writing asm? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: the asm's only job is to create the bitmap everything else is in c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack some necessary conditions:

- need a win32 window

  refer: [Creating a Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window)
- need to initialize [IWICImagingFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicimagingfactory) interface

  refer: [How to Load a Bitmap from a File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-load-a-direct2d-bitmap-from-a-file)
- need to use [BindDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1dcrendertarget-binddc?redirectedfrom=MSDN) method to associate it with a `GDI` DC.

  refer: [Direct2D and GDI Interoperability Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-gdi-interoperation-overview)

Modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>

#include <wincodec.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Windowscodecs.lib")

#define SAFE_RELEASE(P) if(P){P->Release() ; P = NULL ;}

extern "C" ID2D1Bitmap* mybitmapcreate(ID2D1DCRenderTarget*);
float left = 5;
float top = 10;
float Bottom = 10;
float Right = 30;
ID2D1Bitmap *pBitmap = NULL;
IWICImagingFactory *pIWICFactory = NULL;

void initize();
void draw();
D2D1_RECT_F myrect = D2D1::RectF(left, top, Bottom, Right);
ID2D1DCRenderTarget* pow;
ID2D1Bitmap* mybitmap;
ID2D1Factory *l;
REFIID x = __uuidof(ID2D1Factory);

HRESULT LoadBitmapFromFile(
    ID2D1RenderTarget *pRenderTarget,
    IWICImagingFactory *pIWICFactory,
    PCWSTR uri,
    UINT destinationWidth,
    UINT destinationHeight
)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    IWICBitmapDecoder *pDecoder = NULL;
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode *pSource = NULL;
    IWICStream *pStream = NULL;
    IWICFormatConverter *pConverter = NULL;
    IWICBitmapScaler *pScaler = NULL;


    hr = pIWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
        uri,
        NULL,
        GENERIC_READ,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
        &pDecoder
    );
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        // Create the initial frame.
        hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pSource);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pIWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pConverter);
    }
    // If a new width or height was specified, create an
// IWICBitmapScaler and use it to resize the image.
    if (destinationWidth != 0 || destinationHeight != 0)
    {
        UINT originalWidth, originalHeight;
        hr = pSource->GetSize(&originalWidth, &originalHeight);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (destinationWidth == 0)
            {
                FLOAT scalar = static_cast<FLOAT>(destinationHeight) / static_cast<FLOAT>(originalHeight);
                destinationWidth = static_cast<UINT>(scalar * static_cast<FLOAT>(originalWidth));
            }
            else if (destinationHeight == 0)
            {
                FLOAT scalar = static_cast<FLOAT>(destinationWidth) / static_cast<FLOAT>(originalWidth);
                destinationHeight = static_cast<UINT>(scalar * static_cast<FLOAT>(originalHeight));
            }

            hr = pIWICFactory->CreateBitmapScaler(&pScaler);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pScaler->Initialize(
                    pSource,
                    destinationWidth,
                    destinationHeight,
                    WICBitmapInterpolationModeCubic
                );
            }
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pConverter->Initialize(
                    pScaler,
                    GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
                    WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
                    NULL,
                    0.f,
                    WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
                );
            }
        }
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Create a Direct2D bitmap from the WIC bitmap.
        hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
            pConverter,
            NULL,
            &pBitmap
        );
    }

    SAFE_RELEASE(pDecoder);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pSource);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pStream);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pConverter);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pScaler);

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcFunc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RECT rc;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        pow->BindDC(ps.hdc, &rc);
        draw();
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WNDCLASS wc{};
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProcFunc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Class_Name";
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Class_Name", L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 1000, 500, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    initize();

    ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG Msg;
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

void initize()
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWICImagingFactory, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pIWICFactory));

    // Create a Direct2D render target.
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        D2D1::PixelFormat(
            DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
            D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
        0,
        0,
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE,
        D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT
    );

    HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &l);
    l->CreateDCRenderTarget(&props, &pow);

}

void draw()
{

    LoadBitmapFromFile(pow, pIWICFactory, L"Path\\test.bmp", 650, 400);


    pow->BeginDraw();

    pow->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));

    D2D1_SIZE_F size = pBitmap->GetSize();
    D2D1_POINT_2F upperLeftCorner = D2D1::Point2F(0.f, 0.f);

    // Draw bitmap
    pow->DrawBitmap(
        pBitmap,
        D2D1::RectF(
            upperLeftCorner.x,
            upperLeftCorner.y,
            upperLeftCorner.x + size.width,
            upperLeftCorner.y + size.height)
    );
    pow->EndDraw();

}
```

There may be some redundancy in the code, you can freely add and delete.

Debug:

[image]

Comment: The only thing id like to add is i did bind my DC, but i did it within the assembly.